# Robot Illustrated Novel about a Man and Talking Ape in Robot World

Tags: story-identification, books, robots, illustrated-story

I'm trying to remember which book series this is.

It was an illustrated novel where it takes place in a future where the human race is replaced with a robot dominant population and a man teams up with a talking gorilla (and maybe a team of others?) where they're trying to survive among these robots. I think the man and the ape team up initially in a jungle? I could be wrong about that.

I saw these books back in early 2000's. The illustrations were oil or acrylic illustrations and the books were sized bigger than 8x11 inches.  I remember the cover of one of the books showing 3-4 of these robots walking in a desert wearing turbans and robes like nomads (almost giving the appearance that robots have replaced humans in function and appearance).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would seem to be [Robota](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0811840417), a 2003 illustrated novel by Orson Scott Card with illustrations by Doug Chaing.

There is a picture of the cover that matches the OP's recollection very closely.

[Robota cover](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51xcO1LNzML._AC_SY400_.jpg)

The summary from Amazon also fits the information supplied by the OP in the question.

> Academy award winning artist Doug Chiang and best-selling sci-fi author Orson Scott Card join forces for an extraordinary publishing adventure: Robota. An original illustrated science fiction novel, Robota follows the fortunes of a strangely powerful amnesiac named Caps as he navigates an ancient, decaying world in which a dwindling human population battles a society of merciless robot warriors. Aided by talking animals and stalked by terrifying hunter robots, Caps slowly rises to fulfill an awesome destiny. Integrating word and image, Card's masterful storytelling is interwoven with 75 pieces of Chiang's wildly imagined, meticulously rendered art. Packaged in a dramatic metallic case, this unusual and powerful collaboration is tailor-made to thrill.